# Editing my answer without my permission.

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

An edit to the answer I posted was not approved by me and still the edit is visible/effective, how?, moderators used their special privilege?

Comment: And again, why downvote here?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/editing) is some information from our Help Center about the SE model vis a vis editing others' posts.

Comment: And I downvoted this question for two reasons: (1) its accusatory tone, and (2) the obvious lack of research you did before asking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are welcome to edit your own answer again, or even to completely undo the edits that were done by others.

Comment: If you mean this answer, however http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/819226/revisions , the edit simply fixed some LaTeX syntax that you were not familiar with.

Answer (score 7):

When you post anything on this site, you are giving implicit permission to other users to use or modify your post.  Any user can do this, if their edit is approved by another user. Edits by users with 2,000 reputation points do not require approval.  At present, there are around 1,000 users who have 2,000 points.

(Your permission was given when you agreed to  [the site's Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal).  The permission is mentioned at the bottom of each page:

[image: TOS footer]

(The part that says "user contributions licensed under…" means that your contributions are considered to be licensed under that license, which means that they may be used or modified by other people; [full details are here](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).)

In short, that is how the site works.

Comment: This is true, but it isn't the whole story. Others *can* edit your posts, but on Math.SE there is a strong preference to limit such edits to copyediting such as fixing LaTeX, spelling, and markdown errors. Unlike some other Stackexchange sites, we do not encourage or expect users to significantly change the *content* of other users' posts, unless the other user has indicated that the answer is open for everyone to edit.  In this case, though, I am not sure which question the OP was concerned about.

Comment: I was addressing the stated claim that the edit was made "without permission"; I also addressed the user's question about whether the edit was done by moderators using their special privilege.

Comment: @MJD, thnx, things are now more clear.

Comment: @CarlMummert,@MJD, I saw the edited version after one hour it was in effect, which disturbed me as I was under the impression that only I can approve edits to my replies.